# The Value of a Limit related to ERF

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, analysis

How do we calculate the value of $$\lim_{k\to \infty}I(k)$$where $$I(k):=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-k^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}dx$$ whence I already know that if we take the derivative of the inner side and make an exchange of variables then $$\int^\infty_0I’(k)dk=-2(\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt)^2$$
But here we do not assume the value of the improper integral in the latter bracket.

Comment: By Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, $0<\frac{e^{-k^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}<\frac{1}{1+x^2}=f(x)$, and $f(x)$ is integrable on $[0;\infty)$.
Therefore, you are allowed to take the limit under the integral sign.
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-k^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\lim_{k\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{e^{-k^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}\bigg)dx$$
Or, even simpler, 
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-k^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}dx=e^{-k^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-k^2x^2}}{1+x^2}dx<e^{-k^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
The limit follows.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you, so the limit is just 0, and hence the latter limit has value -pi/2, right?

Comment: If you mean the last integral - yes, $\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2} =\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment*

You can also get the closed form for the initial integral.
$$I(k)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-k^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}dx=ke^{-k^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t^2}}{k^2+t^2}dt$$
Using $\frac{1}{k^2+t^2}=\int_0^\infty e^{-p(k^2+t^2)}dp$ and changing the order of integration
$$I(k)=ke^{-k^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt\int_0^\infty e^{-p(k^2+t^2)}dp=ke^{-k^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-pk^2}dp\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2(1+p)}dt$$
$$=ke^{-k^2}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-pk^2}}{\sqrt{1+p}}dp=ke^{-k^2}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-(x-1)k^2}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
$$=ke^{-k^2}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}e^{k^2}\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-xk^2}}
{\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt\pi \,k\int_1^\infty e^{-t^2k^2}dt=\sqrt\pi\int_k^\infty e^{-s^2}ds$$
The limits are now evident:
$$\lim_{k\to0}I(k)=\sqrt\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-s^2}ds=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Integrating by part, at $\,k\to\infty$
$$I(k)=-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\int_k^\infty \frac{d(e^{-s^2})}{s}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\frac{e^{-k^2}}{k}-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\int_k^\infty \frac{e^{-s^2}}{s^2}ds=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\frac{e^{-k^2}}{k}+O\Big(\frac{e^{-k^2}}{k^3}\Big)$$